# Can someone explain how this code works?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having difficulty getting the create function of [`backbone.js`](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L531) to work. My main question, is where do `nextModel`, `resp`, `xhr` come from?
I thought it should be doing `coll.add(model)` ('coz we're trying to add a model to the collection).

Thank you.

```
create : function(model, options) {
    var coll = this;
    options || (options = {});
    model = this._prepareModel(model, options);
    if (!model) return false;

    var success = options.success;

    options.success = function(nextModel, resp, xhr) {
        coll.add(nextModel, options);
        if (success) success(nextModel, resp, xhr);
    };
    model.save(null, options);
    return model;
},
```

---

UPDATE:
This is what I learned following clues from shesak. I tracked it down, from Create to Save then to Backbone.sync. The options.success at the end will correspond to this in Jquery

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array
```

A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments:

- the data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter
- a string describing the status
- and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event. Which means, `nextModel` would come from the data of `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`.

Comment: Not exactly. The code that calls the success callback is `Backbone.Model#save`, which passes it with an `Backbone.Model` object loaded with the data provided to `Backbone.Collection#create`, merged with the JSON response from the server - and not the actual AJAX response.

Comment: @ Shesek, so does it ADD the model I give it to the collection or add the model responded from server to the collection.

Comment: @ Shesek, so far, I received a resp from the server in the options.success of SAVE, and I can alert out the resp. However, the "success" state wasn't transferred back to CREATE, so its success function wasn't called.

Comment: It takes the model you initially give it, adds on top of it any attributes the server returned in the JSON response, and adds this to the collection. The original model you give it + the data from the server is what being refereed to as `nextModel`. This is also what the success callback defined at `Backbone.Collection#create` gets as the first argument. I didn't understand the second comment you wrote - is the success callback not being called at all? If so, open a new question with more details about the way you're using it

Comment: @shesek, turns out it was stopped when SET was called and returned false, i'm going through the set code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `options` object, along with the `success` callback, are passed to `Backbone.Model#save`, which saves a copy of the `success` callback, overrides it with its own callback and calls `Backbone.sync`, which eventually calls `$.ajax` with the entire `options` object. Its jQuery's (or Zepto's) code that eventually calls the (overridden) `options.success` with the JSON response from the server.

The overridden success callback `set()`s the response from the server on the model (the server, after saving the model, can return either the entire model of it or just some of the attributes in JSON format. This is done to allow the server to modify or normalize the model when saving it [like adding the newly created ID]), and passes the changed model (that changed model is what being referred to as `nextModel`) back to the saved copy of the original `success` callback (the one defined in `Backbone.Collection#create`), which adds that `nextModel` (as passed from `Backbone.Model#save`, after being modified by the JSON response from the server) to the collection.

---

If you just want to add a model to the collection, without saving it in persistent storage by the server, call `Backbone.Collection#add` directly instead of create.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(nextModel, resp, xhr)
```

is anonymous function which will be called when execution is successful and parameters netModel, resp, xhr will be passed to it.

so somewhere in model there is method that will call function

```
options.success(nextMode, resp, xhr)
```

and those variables are defined in model

Comment: Neither your answer nor @ctcherry 's answer addresses the question; check the code, `nextModel` only exists within this function, and isn't defined elsewhere. Where is it assigned, and why is it being used?

Comment: I did a search through the entire Backbone.js...nextModel only appeared here. Where did it come from?

Comment: nextModel is name of parameter, so it can be called in model "x" or "j" or "xxx" or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `nextModel, resp, xhr` that you refer to are arguments to a function. That functuon is created and assigned to `options.success`

Just after that point in the code, the entire `options` object is passed into `model.save` where I imagine some more processing takes place and perhaps that `options.success` function is called, and 3 arguments are passed into it at that point.